# Nested gridview checkboxes are not toggling when master gridview checkbox is toggled

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox, nested

I have the following code ...

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvStudents" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceStudents" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" OnRowDataBound="gvStudents_RowDataBound">
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" ForeColor="White" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Student" ControlStyle-Width="120px" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StudentName") %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("ProgramName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mobile" ControlStyle-Width="70px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblMobile" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StudentMobilePhone") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Next Of Kin" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign ="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign ="Left" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="gvNOKs" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderStyle="None" GridLines="Vertical" ShowHeader="false" ShowFooter="false" >
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Given Name" ControlStyle-Width="150px" >
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblNOKGivenName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NOKname") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NoK Type" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ControlStyle-Width="100px" >
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblNOKType" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NOKType") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mobile" ControlStyle-Width="100px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblNOKMobile" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NOKMobile") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbNOKAdd" runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                   </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox id="CheckBoxAll" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBoxAll_OnCheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxAdd" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBoxAdd_OnCheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The problem is that when I toggle the "CheckBoxAll" checkbox, I have a C# code behind (CheckBoxAll_OnCheckedChanged) that has to iterate through all the "CheckBoxAdd" checkboxes and toggle them to match the main checkbox. That works fine.

But what is not happening is the nested gridview "cbNOKAdd" checkboxes are not also being toggled. I expected them to also change because the code behind in the CheckBoxAdd_OnCheckedChanged() procedure does that for you.

In other words, running CheckBoxAll_OnCheckedChanged() on its own, and toggling the "CheckBoxAdd" checkboxes, does not toggle the nested gridview checkboxes.

Does ASP.net force programmers to code every event, of every control even though some controls are managed by parent code?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your first `CheckBoxAll_OnCheckedChanged` you will be running through each checkbox and changing its `Checked` to True or False dependent on what the `CheckBoxAll` has been ticked as.

This will **not** cause a postback on the checkbox per one being run.

Instead, while looping through the nested gridview you can call the `CheckBoxAdd_OnCheckedChanged` sub by just passing the object and same eventargs over to it.

For example:

```
Sub CheckBoxAll_OnCheckedChanged(sender as object, e as eventargs)
    'Loop through gridview here
    'When finding the control CheckBoxAdd just call
     For each gvRow as GridviewRow in gvStudents.Rows
         dim CheckBoxAdd as Checkbox = gvRow.FindControl("CheckBoxAdd")
         CheckBoxAdd.Checked = True 'Or false dependent on CheckBoxAll
         CheckBoxAll_OnCheckedChanged(CheckBoxAdd, e)
     Next
End Sub
```

This will send the object the exact same way as clicking the checkbox originally would have.